# How to get Word for Mac docs to open in a new window by default on my Mac Air?

Tags: ms-office

Can anyone tell me how to set the default so that when I select a Word doc from Finder it opens in a new window? Currently, it opens in the same window as the existing Word doc/s, obscuring the ones below. yes I know I can press the green button to make it full screen in which case it opens a new window but I didn't have to do that in the past. It's driving me nuts!

PS I'm using Word for Mac 15.13.3 on a MacBook Air running Sierra 10.12.6

Comment: This is not clear.... All Word documents open in a new window and brings it to the forefront because it assumes that's the document you want to work on.  Can you post a picture of what you're experiencing and perhaps also another with the windows rearranged to show your expected outcome?

Comment: I think we're looking for 'auto fullscreen' rather than 'new window', but idk Word & I don't use fullscreen, so can't really help other than that.